# How do I start the file path from the users directory?

Tags: python, windows, macos, filepath

I am trying to create a script in python that creates a text file on the user's desktop. I need this to work on both Mac and Windows but it doesn't need to be in the same script as I have one script for mac and one for Windows. I can't seem to find a way for python to create a file with the path beginning at the user's directory (like ~/ for Linux) as I don't know the user's username. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same `~` across different platforms with [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code for windows as python isn't throwing an error but the file isn't being created? (Mac worked fine thanks!)

Comment: @SpaceFlier Just `os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")` should work.